# Weird LLVM Unsigned to Signed Conversion in For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, llvm, unsigned, signed

I am not sure if this only happens on **Apple's LLVM Compiler 4.0 (XCode 4.4.1)**, but I noticed the following behaviour:

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;
NSUInteger sideSize = 2;

// Method A
for (NSInteger i = currentIndex-sideSize; i < currentIndex+sideSize; i++)
{
    printf("In the loop\n"); // WON'T be executed
}

// Method B
for (NSInteger i = (NSInteger)(currentIndex-sideSize); i < currentIndex+sideSize; i++)
{
    printf("In the loop\n"); // WON'T be executed
}

// Method C
for (NSInteger i = (NSInteger)(currentIndex-sideSize); i < (NSInteger)(currentIndex+sideSize); i++)
{
    printf("In the loop\n"); // WILL be executed
}

// Method D
NSInteger initialIndex = currentIndex-sideSize;
NSInteger finalIndex = currentIndex+sideSize;
for (NSInteger i = initialIndex; i < finalIndex; i++)
{
    printf("In the loop\n"); // WILL be executed
}
```

Method B and Method C are almost the same except we are not explicitly casting the result of the addition operator to a signed value.

Can anyone please explain what is happening?

Comment: +1, because I didn't know about this for some time until I did a quiz on integers. At work, I run in this problem also (some 2 weeks before) and I was glad I knew why on Earth were all the negative numbers near to positive infinity... (I multiplied the erronous results with a float).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that if in an expression there are signed and unsigned operands, as per the C standard, the signed operand will be promoted to **unsigned** integer. What happens then is if you subtract 2 from 0, that results in -2, but since it's treated as an unsigned integer (when comparing the values), it's overflowing and ends up being some large number. That's why the loop in Method B doesn't execute and the loop in Method C does (when you explicitly cast the result and/or the operands to signed, the overflow doesn't occur and the loop correctly goes from -2 to 2).

That's a weird thing in the C standard, not in LLVM. LLVM perfectly follows the standard here.

Comment: But why Method C works and Method B does not? They are just adding numbers, so the result should be a positive integer (unsigned or signed).

Comment: @jlukanta see, it's also isn't enough to cast the value of the whole expression - you have to cast the operands themselves. In C, you made the same error twice :) They nulled out each other, but in B, i is initially that large overflowed number, but the condition says 'i < 2' which is false by default.

Comment: Hmm... I am still confused. What about Method A vs Method D? Are they not equivalent? Why would one fail, but not the other one? Thanks very much for answering :)

Comment: @jlukanta well, it seems that they aren't :) (you *better stop using unsigned integers*... ;)

Comment: Gotcha. I will try to summarize what I now understand. In Method B, the code "i < currentIndex+sideSize" will promote the "i" from signed to unsigned because "currentIndex+sideSize" is unsigned. In Method C, by explicitly casting the right operand to signed, the compiler can properly compare the two expressions because they are of the same type (signed). There is no promotion because there is no ambiguity. Likewise, the left operand in Method A will be promoted to a huge unsigned number, which prevents the loop from being executed. Method D works the same as Method C (no promotion).

Comment: @jlukanta IIRC that's fine :)